# SQL Table sort denomalized table

Tags: sql, sorting

I have 2 tables:

"products" conatains basic product data

```
product_id | product_name | product_picture
1          | test         | pic.jpg
2          | samp         | sam.gif
```

product_details contains details for the products (1 or more per product_id)

```
product_id | unit   | value
1          | size   | 100mm
1          | weight | 100g
2          | size   | 80mm
2          | color  | red
```

Now I want to sort this by size. (a bit like a nomalized table) Result:

```
2 | sample | sam.gif | size | 80mm  | color  | red
1 | test   | pic.jpg | size | 100mm | weight | 100g
```

Programming language is PHP. Usualy I would do it this way (PSEUDOCODE):

```
while (SELECT * FROM a) {
   while(SELECT * FROM b WHERE id = a.id) {
      myarray[a.id][b.unit] = b.value;
   }
}
```

But I don't know how to sort the results. (and I guess sorting with PHP is less performant than SQL?)

edit:
New idea: First do a query to select the product_ids in right order:

```
while(SELECT products_id FROM products INNER JOIN products_details USING(products_id) WHERE unit = 'size' ORDER BY value) {
   while( SELECT value, unit FROM products_details WHERE products_id = id) {
      myarray[a.id][b.unit] = b.value;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it normalised, you should have different types of properties in different columns. Basically, you need to *unpivot* your properties. One way would be to use conditional aggregation, like this:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,
  p.product_name,
  p.product_picture,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'size'   THEN d.value END) AS size,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'weight' THEN d.value END) AS weight,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'color'  THEN d.value END) AS color
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_details d
ON p.product_id = d.product_id
GROUP BY
  p.product_id,
  p.product_name,
  p.product_picture
;
```

That will give you a dataset like this:

```
product_id  product_name  product_picture  size   weight  color
----------  ------------  ---------------  -----  ------  -----
1           test          pic.jpg          100mm  100g    NULL
2           samp          sam.gif          80mm   NULL    red
```

Once you've assigned a separate column for every property, you can sort the rows any way you like. For instance:

```
SELECT
  p.product_id,
  p.product_name,
  p.product_picture,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'size'   THEN d.value END) AS size,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'weight' THEN d.value END) AS weight,
  MAX(CASE d.unit WHEN 'color'  THEN d.value END) AS color
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN product_details d
ON p.product_id = d.product_id
GROUP BY
  p.product_id,
  p.product_name,
  p.product_picture
ORDER BY
  weight,
  color,
  size
;
```